# how to filter only vectors that contain all uppercase letters in all the strings in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I need to filter rows that are uppercase in R. I managed to use the following code:

```
filter(str_detect(fruit, "^[:upper:]+$"))
```

However, some of the values of the column "fruit" contain two or three strings, and the code above only works for the cases when there is only one string. I can't share the data, but this example works for my purposes (only the str_detect part)

```
fruit <- c("apple", "ORANGE", "kiwi" ,"TWO PEARS", "A BIG PINEAPPLE", "LEMON")
str_detect(fruit, "^[:upper:]+$")
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

What I want is to also be able to identify "TWO PEARS" and "A BIG PINEAPPLE". Could you please help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: can you just negate the result for looking for lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include the space character class.

```
stringr::str_detect(fruit, "^[[:upper:][:space:]]+$")
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Following the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62999156/how-to-filter-only-vectors-that-contain-uppercase-letters-in-all-the-strings-in/62999220#comment111406304_62999156) to the question, negate uppercase:

```
stringr::str_detect(fruit, "^[^[:lower:]]+$")
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rui Barradas it works! I used ! expression to negate uppercase: filter(!str_detect(fruit, "^[:upper:]+$")), but I prefer your solution.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grep` in `base R`

```
grep("^[A-Z ]+$", fruit, value = TRUE)
#[1] "ORANGE"          "TWO PEARS"       "A BIG PINEAPPLE" "LEMON"
```

To get the other elements

```
grep("^[A-Z ]+$", fruit, value = TRUE, inverse = TRUE)
```